# Relationship between delay and fractional order differential equation

Tags: control-theory, fractional-calculus, delay-differential-equations

There are control systems with delay [[1]](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~buckman/H3.pdf)

There are differential equations with fractional order:

$$D^\alpha x(t)=f(t,x(t))$$

I am wondering why we see control systems with delay and fractional order ODE together a lot in many researches such as [[2]](http://ave.dee.isep.ipp.pt/~gris/_private/JTM_FCAA01.pdf), [[3]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Serdar_Hamamci/publication/3032897_An_Algorithm_for_Stabilization_of_Fractional-Order_Time_Delay_Systems_Using_Fractional-Order_PID_Controllers/links/02e7e515f5e2d0d24c000000.pdf), [[4]](http://www.ugcfrp.ac.in/images/userfiles/41169-JOTA.pdf), [[5]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan_Trujillo/publication/270279223_2007-CAP_Libro_Advances_in_Fractional_Calculus-_Theoretical_Developments_and_Applications_in_Physics_and_Engineering/links/54a5cb5c0cf267bdb9082a6a.pdf)?

Is there any relationship between control system with time delay and fractional order to bind them together? or we see them together just because both are under control theory?

I also have found this quote from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Juan_Trujillo/publication/226837137_On_Deterministic_Fractional_Models/links/0912f50b7ba19a7e4b000000.pdf):

*Therefore, the fractional models are a good and natural alternative to the
known classical non-local equations called “delay differential equations”*

Comment: in the Fourier domain, a delay is a multiplication by $e^{2i \pi a\xi}$ while a fractional derivative is a multiplication by $(2 i \pi \xi)^\alpha$

Comment: Note that calculus has applications, so it is only natural (sorta pun?) for fractional calculus to have similar applications... and then some.